# SCP Policy to Deny public access to S3 buckets with condition to allow whitelisted buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, conditional-statements, policy

I am writing an SCP policy to Deny public access to S3 buckets

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyBlockPublicAccess",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::blockpublicaccesstest"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to put a condition to whitelist a bucket. I can't seem to find the key for that. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about using `NotResource` instead of `Resource`, and removing the `Condition`? That is, use: `"NotResource": "arn:aws:s3:::blockpublicaccesstest"`

Comment: Already tried that. I get this error
` SCP Syntax Error Notresource: SCPs do not support the NotResource element. Update the policy to use Resource instead.`

Comment: In that case, you're probably not going to be able to make a policy for "every bucket except one".

Comment: Hence the question. Is there a way to do it? I can set a condition to whitelist an account
`"Condition": {
    "StringNotEquals": {
         "aws:PrincipalAccount": [
                "123456789012"
          ]
     }
}`

But can a condition be set to whitelist a bucket?